# An elegant way to transform an index by table into simple table in PL/SQL, other then loop through every entry

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have two types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_record_type IS OBJECT
  (
    name        varchar2(30)
  )
  ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_table_type AS TABLE OF my_record_type
```

and a function

```
create or replace my_function return my_table_type
is
  type my_hash_type is table of my_record_type index by pls_integer;
  v_hash my_hash_type;
  v_table my_table_type;
  i NUMBER;
begin
 -- some business logic here

 -- transformation part

 v_table := my_table_type();
 i := v_hash.first;

 while i is not null loop

  v_table.extend(1);
  v_table(v_table.last) := v_hash(i);
  i := v_hash.next(i); 

 end loop;

 --  end transformation part

 return v_table;
end;
/
```

Is there an elegant way in 10g to replace the transformation part with something like

```
v_table = CAST( v_hash as  my_table_type )
```

Comment: It looks like you don't care about the actual keys *themselves* in `v_hash`, just their order. If that's the case, why use an INDEX BY table at all?

Comment: If `MY_HASH_TYPE` is a table of `MY_RECORD_TYPE`, just like `MY_TABLE_TYPE`, why not just declare V_HASH as of type `MY_TABLE_TYPE`?  Then you can do away with V_TABLE and just RETURN V_HASH.  Unless there's some subtlety of your business logic which is missing from your sample code.

Comment: @APC: I use the hash in the `-- some business logic here` part :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `SELECT my_record_type(column_value) BULK COLLECT INTO v_table from table(v_hash)`.  But in order to use this, you will have to create my_hash_type outside of a function (either as a stand along type **OR** in a Package Specification so it will be visible to the SQL Engine) otherwise you will receive a `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_hash_type is table OF VARCHAR2(10);
/
set serveroutput on
declare 
 --type my_hash_type is table OF VARCHAR2(10);
  v_hash my_hash_type := my_hash_type();
  v_table my_table_type;
  i NUMBER;
begin
null ;
  for n in 60..75 loop
    V_hash.extend(1);  
    V_hash(v_hash.count) := chr(n) ;
  end loop ;

  select my_record_type(column_value)
  bulk collect into  v_table
  from table(v_hash) ;

  for n in 1..v_table.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line( n || ':>' || v_table(n).name);
  end loop ;

  --PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

end ;

1:><
2:>=
3:>>
4:>?
5:>@
6:>A
7:>B
8:>C
9:>D
10:>E
11:>F
12:>G
13:>H
14:>I
15:>J
16:>K
```

have a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) and [here](http://psoug.org/reference/type.html) for some more examples and whatnot

timing differences ([based on this methodology](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch25_01.htm#SQL2-CH-25-SECT-1) #s are in hundreths of a second)

```
pl/sql context switch (as described above)
44
42
43
42

loop fill (with type defined outside of block) --A distinct CREATE TYPE on Oracle level

18
18
18
18

loop fill (with type defined within block) --Type created within the Anon. block
23
22
24
22
```

(the above time trials were variations based on this code:

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
 --type my_hash_type  is table of my_record_type -index by pls_integer;
  v_hash my_hash_type := my_hash_type();
  v_table my_table_type;
  i NUMBER;
  time_before BINARY_INTEGER; 
  time_after BINARY_INTEGER;
begin

time_before := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME; 

  for n in 0..15000 loop
    V_hash.extend(1);  
    V_hash(v_hash.count) := my_record_type(n) ;
  end loop ;


  select my_record_type(column_value)
  bulk collect into  v_table
  from table(v_hash) ;


  /*
  v_table := my_table_type();
  for n in 1..V_hash.count loop
    v_table.extend(1);
    v_table(v_table.count) := v_hash(n) ;
    --dbms_output.put_line( n || ':>' || v_table(n).name);
  end loop ;*/
  --for n in 1..v_table.count loop
  --  dbms_output.put_line( n || ':>' || v_table(n).name);
  --end loop ;
time_after := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME; 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (time_after - time_before);
  --PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

end ;
/
```

Thus the loop fill is 50% faster, but the time difference is still minuscule (here is the balance between premature optimization and avoiding something because it may be too long, I would recommend doing time trials on your real data to find the solution that best fits).

The only other 'elegant' solution I can think of is [TREAT](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions183.htm), but you'll notice it requires a subtype/supertype solution that must be on an object type (I couldn't get it to work on an Varray/Assoc. Array type -- hopefully I'm wrong!)

Comment: +1 nice solution, but wouldn't it have performance impact due to the switches **plsql-> sql -> plsql** ?

Comment: @schurik, I added some time differences between the sql-pl/sql switch as well as the looping.  You will notice there is a 50% reduction in time on looping.

Comment: thanks for the detailed investigation of my question, but what do you mean with **type defined outside/within the block** ?

Comment: @schurik added more detail, but the **type defined outside** block was to indicate a 'Create Type xyz as object();' whereas the w/in block was 'DECLARE type xyz as....begin...'